# Как преобразовать дату в формат Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, время

Я делаю сигнального бота и у меня возникла проблема с переводом даты в формат Datetime
11 октября среда 19:00 дата вот такого формата и её нужно перевести в формат datetime что бы сравнивать с текущей датой

Comment: Нет даты без года

Comment: Если это некая ежегодная дата, то это будет не всегда среда и нужно подставлять текущий год. Если вопрос в русской локали, то посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839678/how-to-use-russian-date-string-with-strptime